JetBrains Rider, how to prevent auto indent when I linebreak before a parenthesis
I've been through the Settings>Editor>Code Style>C# options but I can't see anything that prevents the IDE to add an indent in this situation:
Console.WriteLine(
    myClass.myMethod(
        new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 7 })
);

Here I want to press return after the closing curly brace and before the closing parenthesis.
I'd expect this:
Console.WriteLine(
    myClass.myMethod(
        new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 7 }
    )
);

But I get this:
Console.WriteLine(
    myClass.myMethod(
        new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 7 }
        )
);

And I actually see the aligned-with-my-desires format happening for a milisecond but then the IDE adds a new indent.
How can I disable this?

I can confirm that, it doesn't seem to be possible

Given that formatting your statement results in a desired formatting, this is most likely a bug in the handler of "Enter" key. I've create a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-497400 , feel free to vote to track a progress

@DmitryOsinovskiy No one answered to the issue? Is that normal?

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows We don't answer to issues unless something is unclear, besides it would be strange if I would answer to myself :) I'll try to fix it, but I cannot give hard promises about how much time it would take.

Ah ok I thought it hadn't gone through, I didn't realize you were assigned to it, so all good!
